# New table created with postgres from two existing tables has smaller size on disk than either existing table?

Tags: postgresql

I created a new table in Postgres by selecting and inner joining data from two previously existing tables.

Prior to doing so, I removed some columns from one of the existing tables.

DBeaver shows the sizes of the existing two tables as:

- `3.2G`
- `1.7G`

The new table I have created has a size of:

- `916M`

Should I be concerned by this? It looks as if there must be some data lost because 916 Mb/MB is clearly smaller than 3.2+1.7 Gb/GB.

However I suspect this is highly unlikely. The more likely explanation could be that removing the existing columns has not "compacted" the data on disk, and it is now in a fragmented state.

Is this a plausable explanation, and is there any way to check? For example, is it possible to ask Postgres to perform some kind of space on disk optimization after removing some columns?

---

##### Update after running `vacuum full`:

I ran `vacuum full` and now my table sizes are:

- `1.3G`
- `202M`

the table combining the data from both is now of size

- `916M`

Comment: You say inner join. How many rows did match each other?

Comment: Did you look at the sizes before you removed the columns?

Comment: @Bergi For every row in Table B there is a corresponding row in Table A. Every row in Table A has 1 or more corresponding rows in Table B. (Standard foreign key relationship.) Unfortunatly I did not look at the sizes before removing data.

Comment: If the data are consistent in the table with the old then there is no problem. As far as space management see the documentation for [Vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how DBeaver calculates table size but indexes could play a big role in this. If there are indexes on the old tables (A and B) and no indexes on the new table (C) it would make sense their total size is bigger. You can check with `pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('A'))` and `pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size('A'))`.

Also consider which columns from A and B you actually saved into C. If you didn't save all columns from A and B into C and use the same data types it makes perfect sense that C is smaller than A + B because you are storing less data.

Comment: How does one get access to `pg_size_pretty`? Do I have to install something extra?

Comment: You should not need to, its a standard Postgres function 
https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_size_pretty.html